# Recursively replace item in array based on another array's values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the noob question, but I'm new at JavaScript.

I have these arrays:

```
const files = ['pt_rBR.xlf', 'it.xlf', 'es.xlf']
const language_map = [{'file': 'de.xlf', 'lang': 'de_DE'},{'file': 'es.xlf', 'lang': 'es_ES'},{'file': 'it.xlf', 'lang': 'it_IT'},{'file': 'pt-rBR.xlf', 'lang': 'pt_BR'}]
```

What I'd like to do is to create a new array where the elements of array "files" are replaced by the values of array "language_map" - the keys of "language_map" are the elements of "files", so like:

```
languages = ['pt_BR', 'it_IT', 'es_ES']
```

How do I set out to do so?
I know that I can loop through the elements of "files" like so:

```
for (const element of files) { 
    console.log(element);
}
```

but how do I do the actual replacement and creation of the new array?

Thank you

Comment: [There’s work to be done, whether it is homework or an assigned task , the person to whom it was assigned is expected to complete it. Even if it seems the task is too hard or there isn’t a clear starting point, an effort should be made.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the below should do what you need.

```js
const files = ['pt-rBR.xlf', 'it.xlf', 'es.xlf']
const language_map = [{'file': 'de.xlf', 'lang': 'de_DE'},{'file': 'es.xlf', 'lang': 'es_ES'},{'file': 'it.xlf', 'lang': 'it_IT'},{'file': 'pt-rBR.xlf', 'lang': 'pt_BR'}]
const languages = [];
var k=0;

// POPULATE ARRAY
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < language_map.length; j++) {
    if(files[i]==language_map[j]['file']) {
     languages[k]=language_map[j]['lang'];
     k++;
    }
  }
}

// OUTPUT ARRAY
for (let z = 0; z < languages.length; z++) {
  alert(languages[z]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dean! This also helps me understanding how arrays actually work in js,
Cheers!

Comment: No problem Enrico - If this answers your question, please mark as answer